# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z = x^2+y^2$, $z = 4 - x^2-y^2$ using cylindrical coordinates.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z = x^2+y^2, z = 4 - x^2-y^2$.

---

$z\in[0,4]$ and $\theta\in[0, 2\pi]$. For $ y=0 $ we have $z=x^2=r^2\cos^2\theta$. $r^2\cos^2\theta\in[0,4]\rightarrow r\in[0,2\cos\theta]$

---

$\iint_D (4– x^2–y^2– x^2–y^2)dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}r(4-2r^2)drd\theta$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct, for at least two reasons.

- The expression $\iint_D (4–x^2–y^2–x^2–y^2)\,dx\,dy$ does indeed find the required volume, but it's a double integral, not a triple integral. Even if you convert $x$ and $y$ into polar coordinates, you will have a double integral in polar coordinates, not a triple integral in cylindrical coordinates, as the exercise requires.
- But then, your conversion to polar coordinates is incorrect. Why the cross-section $y=0$? This is quite random, at best. Instead, you must project the solid onto the $xy$-plane in order to see what the domain of integration $D$ is. Another way to see it in this example is to find the intersection of the two paraboloids (where they are the widest, so to speak).

Comment: So, for example $x\in[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]$ and $y\in[-\sqrt{2-x^2},\sqrt{2-x^2}]$

Comment: @Michael: Yes, in cartesian coordinates that's correct. But it becomes even easier when switching to polar. (And cylindrical coordinates in 3D is precisely switching $x$ and $y$ to polar $\rho$ and $\theta$, while keeping $z$ unchanged.)

Answer (score 0):

By using polar form the integral you need is $$4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^\sqrt2\int_{r^2}^{4-r^2}r\ dz\ dr\ d\theta $$

Comment: I wanted to solve it using cylindrical coordinates

Comment: @Michael then you should specify that in your question.